# HTML5 geolocation demo not working

Tags: html, geolocation

I'm using this example to test geolocation API `http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation_error`

But, I always get `Location information is unavailable.` message. I tested it on different browsers, same problem. I have geolocation enabled in browser.

Also, I tried uploading this to a local server (XAMPP), but problem remains (same error code).

What am I doing wrong here, its taking me hours now?...I appreciate any help on this, thank you.

**EDIT**: When I try to locate myself using this service `http://www.hostip.info/index.html` its giving me error message `... actually we haven't a clue.`. When I type in some random IP address, works perfect. Whats going on here?

Comment: Nope, works for me. I wouldn't advise using that website btw, there are many better resources around

Comment: Any ideas on what could possibly be my problem (or solution for it)?

Comment: what browser are you using

Comment: I am using Chrome at moment. Chrome gives error message almost instantly, while Mozilla...not giving ANY results at all, when I click the button...same is with IE. I still haven't found way to solve this...

Comment: @1atera1us Which version of Chrome? Are you not receiving the         "w3schools wants to use your computers location message?" when clicking 'try it'?

Comment: version 26, that is, latest one I think. I am getting that message, and I allow access. Just, it gets stuck on getCurrentPosition(successHandler, errorHandler) - it doesnt even go through success or error handlers provided.